# Google Sheets Apps Script to Find this weeks date for a day, as well as the follow weeks date for the same day

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a bit of a novice at coding but what I need to do is create a script in Google Sheets that will analyze the current day of the week (for example Tuesday), and if it's Monday or Tuesday, it will show the date of this weeks Tuesday, however, if it's Wednesday through Friday it will show the date for the following Tuesday. I thought I had something working but I was testing on a Friday and once the new week started the script only worked for certain days. I understand the basic math behind this and can write it as a function so I suspect my issue is in the setDate() or getDate() portion of my script:

```
function Testdate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tues');
  var today = new Date();
  var day = 7 - today.getDay() + 2;
  var nextDay = 0 - today.getDay() + 2;
  var thisWeek = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate())+nextDay);
  var nextWeek = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate())+day);
    if(today.getDay() > 2)
      sheet.getRange('E1').setValue(nextWeek).setNumberFormat("DDDD m/d")
        else
          sheet.getRange('E1').setValue(thisWeek).setNumberFormat("DDDD m/d");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computations for your date offsets `day` and `nextDay` are correct.

---

### **Your code has 2 main issues:**

1. You did not add the offset on the current `today.getDate()` when you tried to adjust the current date.

   `var thisWeek = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate())+nextDay);`

- It should be `var thisWeek = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+nextDay));`

2. But if you will do the step1, you basically lost your original `today` date.

**For example:**

```
  Logger.log(today.getDay());
  var thisWeek = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+nextDay));
  var nextWeek = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+day));

  Logger.log(today.getDay());
  if(today.getDay() > 2){
    Logger.log("Next:"+nextWeek);
    sheet.getRange('E1').setValue(nextWeek).setNumberFormat("DDDD m/d")
  }else{
    Logger.log("This"+thisWeek);
    sheet.getRange('E1').setValue(thisWeek).setNumberFormat("DDDD m/d");
  }
```

**Output:**

```
7:37:44 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:37:45 AM  Info    1.0
7:37:45 AM  Info    3.0
7:37:45 AM  Info    Next:Wed Feb 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)
7:37:46 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- Originally, lets say the current day is Monday. But since you modified your today date using `today.setDate()`, your new day will be Wednesday.

---

**Sample Working Code:**

```
function Testdate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tues');
  var today = new Date();
  var day = 7 - today.getDay() + 2;
  var nextDay = 0 - today.getDay() + 2;

  var nextWeek = new Date();
  nextWeek.setDate(today.getDate()+day);

  var thisWeek = new Date();
  thisWeek.setDate(today.getDate()+nextDay);

  Logger.log(today.getDay());
  if(today.getDay() > 2){
    sheet.getRange('E1').setValue(nextWeek).setNumberFormat("DDDD m/d")
  }else{
    sheet.getRange('E1').setValue(thisWeek).setNumberFormat("DDDD m/d");
  }
}
```

- This sample code did not modified your `today` object. Instead we just read its date using `today.getDate()` and add date `offsets` in setting your `nextWeek` and `thisWeek` dates

Comment: This took me a minute to work my brain through but now makes sense. Thanks so much for your help here.

Comment: Hi @Nick Belle, I thought of a better approach and updated the answer. The updated answer will prevent you from modifying your today date object.

Comment: Thanks for the different approach. I really appreciate it as it reinforced that I was indeed understanding what was wrong with my original attempt.